# Resolvent Kernel of a general Fredholm Equation of second kind

Tags: functional-analysis, integral-equations

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Find the resolvent kernel, and solve the integral equation:

\begin{equation}
u(t) = p(t) + \int_{0}^{x}a(t)b(s)u(s) ds.
\end{equation}

Here we have an integral equation with a separable, Hilbert-Schmidt kernel with a self-adjoint integral operator. I know the standard way of solving integral equations and/or finding eigenfunctions of self-adjoint intgeral operators is to convert the equation into a differential equation. However, I'm not sure how to go about solving this question with this approach. The functions $a(t)$ and $b(s)$ aren't specified, and I'm not sure how this approach would work.

Any suggestions? Please only provide hints as this is a homework problem.

Comment: Currently you have wrote $a(t)$ in the integral. Since this depends only on t, this can be taken outside the integral since the integral does not depend on $t$ (only $x$ and $s$).

Comment: @Yes, but when I try and differentiate it, I get expressions of the form $a^{(n)}(t) \int_{0}^{x} b(s)u(s)ds$. The process repeats indefinitely. I took $a(t)$ to the LHS, and did computations then, but it got very messy.